# mailto link into python-telegram-bot message for letting user send a precompiled email

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

is there a simple way to show a hyperlink for letting user send an email in python-telegram-bot? I've tried this but the link redirects the user to a web page of the email domain. I would have a redirect into a default mail app.

```
context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Contact us <a href='mailto:xxxx@xxxx.xx?cc=xxxx@yyyy.yy&subject=Support%20request%20&body=Write%20here%20your%20issue:'>here</a> to solve the problem together.", parse_mode="HTML")
```

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Telegram does not count mailto links as entities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Telegram doesn't recognize `mailto:` urls. In order to wrap it into an "acceptable" `https` url, you can use the URL shortening services like TinyUrl. This way, the `https` url will redirect into a `mailto` url which is what you want.

Here's an example:

```
$ curl -I https://a-random-url-shortener.com/yhbv7ucf
HTTP/2 308 
...
location: mailto:receiver1@example.com,receiver2@example.com?subject=Example%20Subject&body=Example%20Body
...
```